# Spotify causes system (UI) freeze

Tags: gui, freeze, spotify

Normally your are working normally on Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04 with Spotify installed (although this can apply to other programs too) and suddenly the UI is frozen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a terminal:

```
ctrl + alt + f1 (f1 -> f6 will get a terminal)
```

Find spotify pid:

```
ps -ef | grep spotify | more
```

resulting in something like:

```
sergio   19510  1962  2 15:43 ?        00:00:02 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
sergio   19515 19510  0 15:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/spotify/spotify --type=zygote --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --log-file=/usr/share/spotify/debug.log --log-severity=disable --product-version=Spotify/1.0.28.89
sergio   19533 19510  0 15:43 ?        00:00:01 /usr/share/spotify/spotify --type=gpu-process --channel=19510.0.1439192124 --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --log-file=/usr/share/spotify/debug.log --log-severity=disable --product-version=Spotify/1.0.28
.89 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=2,51,63 --disable-gl-extensions=GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x0a16 --gpu-driver-vendor --gp
u-driver-version --lang=en-US --log-file=/usr/share/spotify/debug.log --log-severity=disable --product-version=Spotify/1.0.28.89 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
sergio   19548 19515  4 15:43 ?        00:00:06 /usr/share/spotify/spotify --type=renderer --disable-pinch --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --lang=en-US --log-file=/usr/share/spotify/debug.log --log-severity=disable --product-version=Spotify/1.0.28.89
 --disable-extensions --disable-spell-checking --num-raster-threads=2 --content-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553 --video-image-texture-target=3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel
=19510.1.1432446137 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
sergio   20233  7137  0 15:46 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn spotify
```

there you will have the process id to kill it:

```
kill -9 19510
```

And go back to UI:

```
ctrl + alt + f7
```

Comment: I would suggest running `kill 19510` first and `kill -9` only if that fails. Also, it might be simpler to run `pgrep spotify` to get the offending PIDs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to some weird conflict with my GPU. Try disabling GPU to rule out a GPU issue:

```
spotify %U --disable-gpu
```